# How Apex transactions work?

Tags: apex, session, triggercontext, transaction, heroku-connect

Part 1:

We have a webpage without login(no session). On the webpage is a submit button when clicked creates a lead. It is integrated using heroku connect.
When a user clicks submit a lead then a record is created in salesforce.
What happens if more than one user simultaneously clicks submit at the same time?
Do we get 10 leads in the same transaction if 10 users click simulatneously?

Part 2:

What happens if more than one user updates or inserts a lead from salesforce record detail page? Do those transactions execute individually or together?

I simply wanted to understand if the records come in a single trigger or those triggers fire independently?

Also please explain if transactions in sessions are any different from other transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have a webpage without login(no session). On the webpage is a submit button when clicked creates a lead. It is integrated using heroku connect. When a user clicks submit a lead then a record is created in salesforce. What happens if more than one user simultaneously clicks submit at the same time? Do we get 10 leads in the same transaction if 10 users click simulatneously?

Specifically, Heroku Connect will check every two minutes, or ten seconds with pg_notify, for updates. Unless the records just barely miss the two minute/ten second polling cycle, they would all likely appear in a single transaction. Your trigger would see 10 records, in a single transaction.

> What happens if more than one user updates or inserts a lead from salesforce record detail page? Do those transactions execute individually or together?

In the UI, every record in a trigger context will be updated by the same user. In other words, ten users clicking save at the exact same millisecond in Salesforce would cause ten **individual** transactions. Because of row locking and collision detection, nine of those should give an error back to the user, with one user being the winner. However, a user performing a List View Action, for example, or using the API, could still generate a single transaction with multiple records.

> Also please explain if transactions in sessions are any different from other transactions?

No, a transaction, by definition, is the start of the top-level DML operation or Apex class execution (e.g. a Queueable execute method) to the end of that operation or execution. In other words, one transaction is one debug log.

By the way, Heroku Connect is still using a session. Just because you don't log in from the website doesn't mean there isn't a session active somewhere. In addition, if you use a Community that doesn't require login, you still have a Guest Session. No actions can occur in Salesforce outside of what Salesforce defines as a session, it just so happens that anonymous sessions are possible.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and brief response!